# Using XPath and PHP to print in all cases

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to extract some information from each URL using XPath and PHP. It is important that something is printed for every URL even if nothing is returned from the XPath query. As a result, I tried to setup my script to print out `N/A` where no results are returned by XPath. However, this `else` clause is never entered and `N/A` is never printed.

The `scrape.txt` contains 50 URLs. Results are returned for 47/50 URL's. I am not concerned about my XPath query, but more so about the script itself returning some value for every URL attempted.

Can someone help me identify why this is happening and help me come up with a way to guarantee some string is printed regardless of whether or not there are results returned from the XPath query?

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Many thanks in advance!

```
$file = fopen('scrape.txt', "r");

$output = array();

while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($line);

    $XPath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $elements = $XPath->query("//ul/li[1]/a[@class='geMain']");

    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                if(strcmp($node->nodeValue, "")!=0){
                    $output[] = trim($node->nodeValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $output[] = "N/A";
    }   
}
array2csv($output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMXpath->query` returns a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domnodelist.php) element, no matter if there are results or not. Test on its `length` value:

```
if ($elements->length == 0) {
  // No results found
} else {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    // for each result
  } 
}
```

Comment: +1, this did exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following, although I am not sure I completely understand what the nature of the problem really is:

```
$file = fopen('scrape.txt', "r");

$output = array();

while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($line);

    $XPath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $elements = $XPath->query("//ul/li[1]/a[@class='geMain']");

    $haveOutput = false;
    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                if(strcmp($node->nodeValue, "")!=0){
                    $output[] = trim($node->nodeValue);
                    $haveOutput = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$haveOutput) {
        $output[] = "N/A";
    }   
}
array2csv($output);
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. I haven't tested this but this seems like it would work.